# How to find the default construstor methods for a class

Tags: r, class, object, r-s4

Problems comes from experimenting a package and find using `new(Class = 'ddmatrix', Data = X)` and `ddmatrix(Data = X)` yields different results, in which `X` is a matrix(one can think class `ddmatrix` is a transformed Class `matrix`).

### Document

In the package, a S4 class `ddmatrix` is defined. A generic constructor function by `setGeneric(name = 'ddmatrix')`. Further, the pacakge defines `setMethod('ddmatrix', signature = 'matrix', ...)` as below:

```
 setMethod("ddmatrix", signature(data="matrix"), 
              function(data, nrow=1, ncol=1, byrow=FALSE, ...
                       bldim=.pbd_env$BLDIM, ICTXT=.pbd_env$ICTXT)
    {
    dim(data) <- NULL
    ret <- ddmatrix(data=data, nrow=nrow, ncol=ncol, byrow=byrow, bldim=bldim, ICTXT=ICTXT)    
    return( ret )
}
)
```

I am confused how a method `ddmatrix` is used in the above `setMethod('ddmatrix', signature = 'matrix')` step. Is this `ddmatrix` method the default method for the generic `ddmatrix`?

Meanwhile, when call `new('ddmatrix', Data = X)`, which method it will call to build a new `ddmatrix` object from a `matrix` object? `new` function is:

```
function (Class, ...) 
{
    ClassDef <- getClass(Class, where = topenv(parent.frame()))
    value <- .Call(C_new_object, ClassDef)
    initialize(value, ...)
}
```

## Question

To answer the discrepancy between `new('ddmatrix')` and `ddmatrix()`, I think one way is to find the default constructor. Meanwhile, the package also defines `setMethod('ddmatrix', signature = 'vector',...)`, is this the default one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At some level this is up to the author. Many people view `new()` and `@` or `slot()` (for slot access) as strictly for the package developer -- these expose the implementation details directly to the user -- and prefer to write constructors and accessors that place an interface on top of the implementation. This appears to be the  case for the package that you are considering, where `ddmatrix()` is meant to be the user-oriented constructor.

The author appears to have implemented a facade pattern, where several different methods make relatively minor data transformations before calling another function / method to do the actual object construction. From what you show, it seems ddmatrix,matrix-method invokes ddmatrix,vector-method (because inside ddmatrix,matrix-method the function sets `dim(data) <- NULL`, turning the matrix into a vector, and then calls `ddmatrix()` which now dispatches to the vector method), and this constructs the object via `new()` at https://github.com/RBigData/pbdDMAT/blob/master/R/constructors.r#L191. A different package author could have adopted a different design, where several methods separately call `new()`.

The documentation often also helps, e.g., `?ddmatrix` does not discuss direct object construction via `new()`.

Here's a simpler example. I create a class "A", with a single slot containing a numeric vector

```
setClass("A", slots=c(x="numeric"))
```

Here I create a constructor, because I want the user to see the interface to the class, rather than it's implementation

```
A = function(x=numeric())
    new("A", x=x)
```

So far, `A()` and `new("A")` return an object with the same structure, e.g.,

```
> new("A")
An object of class "A"
Slot "x":
numeric(0)

> A()
An object of class "A"
Slot "x":
numeric(0)
```

Maybe as the developer of the "A" class, I want an uninitialized object of class 'A' to have 'NA' as the value of the slot x, so I modify

```
A = function(x = NA_real_)
    new("A", x=x)
```

now a direct call to `new()` returns a different object from a call to `A()`

```
> new("A")
An object of class "A"
Slot "x":
numeric(0)

> A()
An object of class "A"
Slot "x":
[1] NA
```

Which one is 'correct'? Well, both are correct, but as the creator of the class I intend for the user to create an object of class "A" by calling the function `A()`.

A typical reason for separating the interface (using `A()` to construct an object) from the implementation (using `new()` to construct an object) is because the implementation is not obvious to the user. This seems to be the case with the `ddmatrix()` function -- for reasons that only the package author needs to know about, it is convenient to store an R matrix as a vector with information about dimensions. I guess a simple equivalent might be

```
setClass("A", slots=c(data="numeric", nrow="integer", ncol="integer"))
A = function(m=matrix(0, 0, 0)) {
    stopifnot(is(m, "matrix"))
    new("A", data=as.vector(m), nrow=nrow(m), ncol=ncol(m))
}
```

for instance

```
> A(matrix(1:10, 5))
An object of class "A"
Slot "data":
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

Slot "nrow":
[1] 5

Slot "ncol":
[1] 2
```

Why does the author want to do this? It doesn't matter to us as users. Why can't we create the same object by calling `m = matrix(1:10, 5); new("A", data=as.vector(m), nrow=nrow(m), ncol(m))`? We could, but then when the author decided to change their implementation such that the offsets to the start of each row were to be stored, we'd have to understand what the author had done and update our code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. By the way, what does your last sentence mean, you mean from the helps it can be shown `ddmatrix` method has no relation with `new` ?

Comment: I meant that the author is telling you how to use their software, and they are saying to use `ddmatrix()` to construct an object. Another author might have written documentation that said to use `new()`.

Comment: As you said, at (https://github.com/RBigData/pbdDMAT/blob/master/R/constructors.r#L191) the method calls `new()` to construct, but then what `new` calls? I think there should be a most basic constructor for `ddmatrix` object

Comment: To see what `new()` calls, type `new` at the command line -- but this is package developer business, not end user business. The package developer intends for you to use one of the `ddmatriix()` methods. By design, all methods lead to ddmatrix,vector-method, so you might think of that as the most basic constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, as I mentioned, using `new('ddmatrix', X)` and `ddmatrix(X)` gives different results. So I am trying to figure out what causes this. My understanding is there should be a basic method. `new` calls when use `new()` to construct the object, and this basic method is also used when calling `ddmatrix()` runs to [position](https://github.com/RBigData/pbdDMAT/blob/master/R/constructors.r#L191), and that the code before that makes the difference.  

`new` calls ` value <- .Call(C_new_object, ClassDef)`, what is done in this step?

Comment: `new()` is a plain old function, so there is no 'basic method' to be called. ddmatrix,vector-method calls `new()` the way the author intends for it to be called. If you constructed arguments Data, dim, ldim, bldim, and ICTXT and used these in your call to new, then (obviously) you would get the same result as calling ddmatrix,vector-method. The .Call creates an unitialized template of the object. Best of luck!

Comment: Still don't understand what you say. If the `ddmatrix.vector-method` calls `new()` the way the author intents for it to be called, then the function `ddmatrix.vector-method` calls itself?